# Which sentence is correct? (Preposition)

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Meet me in lunch room.
Meet me at lunch room.
what should be the preposition in or at?

Answer (score 2):

We generally meet "in" an area or "at" a location. In this case, "the" is needed. Examples:

- Meet me in the lunch room.
- Meet me at the lunch room entrance.
- Meet me at the tables in the lunch room.

If we only have one lunch room, it is "the lunch room". If there is more than one, we need to be even more definite as to where to meet: "Meet me in the blue lunch room".